# android kotlin MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am currently using MPAndroid Chart to draw graphs on Android.

The official document asks me to do the following, but I don't understand what it means.

1. Gradle Setup

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

2. Maven Setup

```
<!-- <repositories> section of pom.xml -->
<repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
   <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>

<!-- <dependencies> section of pom.xml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.PhilJay</groupId>
    <artifactId>MPAndroidChart</artifactId>
    <version>v3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

First of all, is the build.gradle file an app or a project?

Where should I make an app for you?

Where is the pom.xml file?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in build.gradle(project)
make sure you have

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }// you have this line
     }
}
```

in your build.gradle(Module)

```
dependencies {
    //this line
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: also you don't need  Maven Setup